# pagerank python implementation

Tags: python, numpy, pagerank

I want to convert [PageRank MATLAB/Octave implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) to python, but when it comes to:

```
a=array([[inf]])  
last_v = dot(ones(N,1),a)
```

there is a `TypeError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/googcheng/page_rank.py", line 18, in <module>
pagerank(0,0)
File "/home/googcheng/page_rank.py", line 14, in pagerank
last_v = dot(ones(N,1),a)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1819, in ones
a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

some code https://gist.github.com/3722398

Comment: You need to include the traceback when reporting a python exception; it'll remove the need for us to guess.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Along with Marijn's advice, you should also produce an immediately reproducible example (we don't know what `N` is and had to figure out that you had to import `numpy`). Furthermore, this question doesn't really have anything to do with pagerank.

Comment: sorry, title is too wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `ones`, the shape, should be a tuple.  Change `ones(N,1)` to `ones((N,1))`.